# Three.js or glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js

Tags: webgl

Need to animate a 3d model using webgl. But i am confused while choosing between Three.js and glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js. Both of them seem to be extensively used but which is more efficient and easier to learn between them?

Comment: glMatrix is just a matrix math library, not a 3D library. I'm inferring from your question that you're relatively new to 3D. In that case you should use three.js. PS: Even if you were experienced you might use three.js as well. But if you were experienced you wouldn't be asking this question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have time and really want to learn a new technique, including 3D, networking, etc... its better to use the lower level if possible (better yet write everything yourself from scratch).  High level libraries hide details which if learned the hard way give you more power and an intuitive understanding.  With enough imagination and fortitude you can spin up interesting 3D model animations using  glMatrix-0.9.5  with no prior 3D experience. Later on you'll be glad you did.